# Can't bake normal map for specific mesh

Tags: normal-map

I'm trying to make a simple barrel and, for some reason, everytime I try to bake its normal map it just keeps plain blue. I've tried applying the same material on other meshes and it worked just fine, but for some reason it doesn't work on this one.

[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi, I just sent it

Comment: please share the URL it has generated

Comment: Here: https://pasteall.org/blend/6f7e7a254f8244d0a5f212d8674ad875

Comment: there is only one barrel in the file, what kind of bake were you trying to do, were you trying to bake a high-poly towards a low-poly?

Comment: Not now, I'll probably try to do that later but for now I was just trying to bake a map for this simple version.

Comment: a map from what object towards what object?

Comment: actually you can't bake the normals of an object to itself unless you've used the Multiresolution modifier for example but it doesn't seem to be the case here, so I'm missing something here...